# how to refresh the center region of a viewport using button

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

There is button in West region to refresh the center region. But it didn't working. Can anyone help me about it.

I am using viewport as the frame.I'm new in ExtJS.

Comment: Can you give us some more context? what is your exact question, what have you tried, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: You're using a border layout I assume. What is in your center region?

Comment: thank you for your time. I have some combo boxes with a search button in the north panel. and in the center region there are 4 charts.. when I'll click the search button, I want that the center region will be refreshed.... Will i give you the codes???

Comment: If you don't want to share the code, well and good, then at least share some thing relevant to your problem so that we can actually know where you are getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you give provide some code that will be helpful to address your question.

If you want to update the charts, get the id  of the charts and update the charts with the data.  If you want to add totally different components by removing the existing, you can do many ways.. below is one among them.

```
var center = Ext.getCmp('centerRegionId'); 
center.removeAll();
center.add({xtype:panel});//new component
```